# Moving Through 2D Array From JSON_DECODE

Tags: php, arrays, json

I cURL to a page which produces an array of json of the fashion:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Drew"},{"id":2,"name":"Joyce"},{"id":3,"name":"Vick"}]
```

I use `$result = json_decode($json, true)` to get back an associative array.

I am having trouble though iterating through the array though and accessing individual pieces of each json object like the name field. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Another issue is, I was planning to use a `foreach` loop as I might not know the exact length of the array of json objects, is there a way to incorporate the solution to my first issue into a for each loop or other structure that might take in a variable sized array and stop when it reaches the end?

Comment: @Phil foreach loops are a bit daunting to me. I can get through them with single arrays, so I must admit that is my biggest issue. However, even when I attempt to access individual pieces, for instance trying to access the json for joyce, if I try `result[1]['name']` I do not get Joyce or for that matter any name back. I thought this was how I would access it, but apparently not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly simple...

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo 'id: ', $item['id'],
         ', name: ', $item['name'],
         PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo here - http://ideone.com/xwy2zH

Whilst developing, I also highly recommend you enable full error reporting. Set these properties in your development environment's `php.ini` file then restart your web server

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```